# Problems with a Cookbook class set-up in Ruby based on the MVC model

Tags: ruby, csv, model-view-controller

I am writing a class called Cookbook and some of the methods I have created do not work at all. for example, I am not sure on how to create a single method to create a recipe when a CSV file is provided and when is not...that is why I have created "**create(recipe)**" and "**save_to_csv**"_ methods.

These are the tests I must pass:

- The Cookbook class must work with our without a CSV file.
- The Cookbook class works in conjunction with another class Recipe (code also
  provided below for further reference).
- The #destroy method should remove a recipe from the cookbook (when a
  CSV file is not provided).
- The #destroy method should remove a recipe from the CSV file (when a
  CSV file is provided).
- the #create method should store a new recipe in the  CSV file (when a
  CSV file is provided)
- #initialize should load existing recipes in the given csv file located in lib/recipes.csv.

```
    require 'csv'
    require_relative 'recipe'
    
    class Cookbook
    
      def initialize(csv_file_path)
        @recipes = []
        @cookbook = []
        @csv_file_path = "spec/recipes.csv"
      end
    
      def all
        @recipes # this is the array where all the recipes instances will be stored
        @recipes << Recipe.new(@name, @description) # this is the actual method to do so
      end
    
    def create(recipe)
      new = ["#{recipe.name}", "#{recipe.description}"]
      @cookbook << new
      save_to_csv
    end
    
    def save_to_csv
      CSV.open(@csv_file_path, 'w') do |csv|
        @cookbook.each do |row|
          csv << [row]
        end
      end
    end
    
      def destroy(recipe_index)
        @recipes.delete_at(recipe_index.to_i - 1) **# "- 1" because the recipe_index is based on a list provided to the customer that starts with 1, not with 0**
        @recipes
      end
    end


**Recipe class is defined as follows:**
```

```
class Recipe
  attr_reader :name, :description

  def initialize(name, description)
    @name = name
    @description = description
  end
end
```